# If an owner of a Rollup has bigger machines, does anyone who wants to join that particular Rollups refutation game will have to buy bigger machines?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup

If an owner of a Rollup has bigger machines, does that mean anyone who wants to join that particular Rollups refutation game will have to buy bigger machines?

[Question from Professional_Duty800](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/11enw9p/comment/jaqmfip/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: yes, if the throughput of your rollup is bounded by compute, but only up to the maximums allowed by the protocol.

Let's say your rollup executes quickly because it ignores any transactions not intended for it and computations it performs are light. In that case, a smaller machine might be able to keep up with a bigger machine.

But lets say your rollup receives many transactions and performs intense compute on all of them. A bigger machine may be required to keep up with throughtput - smaller machines will just get left behind, and won't be have the correct state with which to challenge bad state commitments.

That said, there are limits to how much compute you can stuff into a rollup. You can see in [the docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mumbai/smart_rollups.html#control-flow) that a rollup can only process 11 billion "ticks" per kernel_run, and can have up to 1000 kernel_runs per Tezos block. This is enforced by the protocol, so even if you had the hardware to go faster, you couldn't without getting slashed. (It's worth noting that right now even the fast execution engine can't keep with 11 billion ticks per block - rollup devs are advised to test their compute consumption with the kernel debugger and keep their consumption well below this limit)

[answer from d4hines](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/11enw9p/questions_on_smart_optimistic_rollups_so_we_can/)